# Editing source code of taglib-sharp (audio metadata)

Tags: c#, powershell, audio, metadata, taglib-sharp

I'm using a program within Powershell called MPTag (Found here: http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/9129.aspx). I want to be able to add a leading zero to track numbers if they are single digits (ie. I want "Track 1" to be "Track 01") but MPTag doesn't seem to accept these leading zeroes (tried putting them in quotes, as a `.tostring`, etc.).

Is it possible to edit the source code of MPTag (which uses a copy of taglib-sharp.dll) to accept the leading zeroes? Maybe changing a variable to a string rather than an integer?

I've downloaded Telerik JustDecompile and the editing extension Reflexil, and I've found variables that affect the track number, but I don't know what steps need to be taken now to make the changes I want. In Reflexil, I can see that I can change variables and calls from system.Uint to system.string. Can someone chime in and help me finish the job? Thanks for any assistance.

EDIT: work-around solution I've found is to use FFMPEG's metadata editor. It allows you to write the leading zero. More info [on this wiki page](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=ffmpeg%20edit%20metadata).

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't possible at all even if you try to do that manually it will be set to 1 instead of 01.

Comment: Is there no way to make a change to allow a string as an input rather than an integer?

Comment: I've found a workaround - FFMPEG's metadata editing allows you to add the leading zero. What a great program.